# Android app crashes by switching the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, crash

I have a Problem with my android app. It always crashes, when I push the Button to go to the new Activity.

**Error:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process:  PID: 15534
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.realliferpgadac.thomas.adacapp/com.realliferpgadac.thomas.adacapp.Feed}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
at android.app.BackStackRecord.configureTransitions(BackStackRecord.java:1244)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.beginTransition(BackStackRecord.java:978)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:707)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**Source code of the activity that crashes: (It should be a RSS Feed)**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;


import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.io.StringReader;

public class Feed extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.tvFeed, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    //@Override
   // public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        //return true;
    //}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.tvFeed) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends ListFragment {

//        private TextView mRssFeed;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

//        @Override
//        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
//                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
//            mRssFeed = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rss_feed);
//            return rootView;
//        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            new GetAndroidPitRssFeedTask().execute();
        }

        private String getAndroidPitRssFeed() throws IOException {
            InputStream in = null;
            String rssFeed = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.androidpit.com/feed/main.xml");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                in = conn.getInputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                for (int count; (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
                rssFeed = new String(response, "UTF-8");
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
            }
            return rssFeed;
        }

        private class GetAndroidPitRssFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

            @Override
            protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                List<String> result = null;
                try {
                    String feed = getAndroidPitRssFeed();
                    result = parse(feed);
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            private List<String> parse(String rssFeed) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                xpp.setInput(new StringReader(rssFeed));
                xpp.nextTag();
                return readRss(xpp);
            }

            private List<String> readRss(XmlPullParser parser)
                    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "rss");
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("channel")) {
                        items.addAll(readChannel(parser));
                    } else {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
                }
                return items;
            }

            private List<String> readChannel(XmlPullParser parser)
                    throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
                List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "channel");
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("item")) {
                        items.add(readItem(parser));
                    } else {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
                }
                return items;
            }

            private String readItem(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                String result = null;
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "item");
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("title")) {
                        result = readTitle(parser);
                    } else {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            // Processes title tags in the feed.
            private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser)
                    throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "title");
                String title = readText(parser);
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "title");
                return title;
            }

            private String readText(XmlPullParser parser)
                    throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
                String result = "";
                if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    result = parser.getText();
                    parser.nextTag();
                }
                return result;
            }

            private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }
                int depth = 1;
                while (depth != 0) {
                    switch (parser.next()) {
                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                            depth--;
                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                            depth++;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<String> rssFeed) {
                if (rssFeed != null) {
                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
                            getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            android.R.id.text1,
                            rssFeed));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XML file of the activity that crashes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.realliferpgadac.thomas.adacapp.Feed">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/tvFeed"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

I hope you can help me.

Thank you,

emt

Comment: `ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`

Comment: You should look at the output from logcat, as it will tell you why the app is crashing.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup  ... 

cast it as Textview and try

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thank you for your answer. I am new in Java developing, so I am sorry for this question, but I don´t find the error in my sourcecode. Where is it and how can i solve it? Thank you!

Comment: if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.tvFeed, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

Comment: here you give your container id ,not the textview id

Comment: also in onOptionsItemSelected  remove that textview id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `R.id.tvFeed` with Framelayout's id or default id `android.R.id.content`.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
```

and remove the code from the onOptionsItemSelected() method.

```
if (id == R.id.tvFeed) {
            return true;
        }
```